# Print Python output on Arduino display

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, arduino-uno

I am completely lost. I'm trying to print something on the Arduino's display using Python. I'm aware that this can be accomplished without Python by using:

```c++
lcd.write("my string");
```

But I'd like to use the pySerial library to do this.

This is my Python code:

```py
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

myvar1 = "text"

arduino.write(myvar1.encode())
```

And this is the code I have on my Arduino:

```c++
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 8, en = 9, d4 = 4, d5 = 5, d6 = 6, d7 = 7;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // initialize the serial communications:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // when characters arrive over the serial port...
  if (Serial.available()) {
    // wait a bit for the entire message to arrive
    delay(100);
    // clear the screen
    lcd.clear();
    // read all the available characters
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      // display each character to the LCD
      lcd.write(Serial.read());
    }
  }
}
```

Also, when I enter text using the Serial Monitor, it shows up on the Arduino like it should (Just has a little sideways "HI!" at the end but that's not a problem).

Answer (score 0):

The serial data may be buffered by Python.

Try:

```
arduino.write(myvar1.encode())
arduino.flush()
```